# Home Automation for my Whole Home

Tags: home-automation

One Help I planned to do home automation for my whole home I already know how to do but there are more than 80 Switches in my home how to control all help

Comment: Your question is unclear. What kind of switches? What have you done? What is not working?

Comment: Sir everything is fine but in a single raspberry pi we can only connect 16 relay(GPIO) i need 80 +

Answer (score 3):

From your question I can try to deduce the following:

- You have a large home with ~80 smart switches/lights/things, etc.
- Based on the fact that you put your question in this forum, you want to control them using a Raspberry Pi.
- You know about how smart items work, but don't know how to control all of them from a Pi, or where to begin.

For someone in your situation, I would highly recommend looking into an open-source solution called [Home Assistant](https://home-assistant.io/).  This open-source app runs on a Pi, and can coordinate the control of a large number of IoT devices from many vendors.  Once you get it running and understand the basics, you can then dive deeper and learn to extend it with custom capabilities.

I hope this helps!  Good luck in whatever you do.

(PS: I am in no way affiliated with the team/community of people that make the Home Assistant app.   I'm just a user of it, and based on your question I think it might fit your needs.)

Comment: Yes friend But i need more than 16 GPIO ports na ?

Comment: So you're saying you want to _directly_ electrically control 80+ relays?  If that's the case, you will need a dedicated addressable multiplexer to allow you control so many.  I recommend looking into the MCP23017 I/O expander chip.  It uses the I2C bus to control up to 16 items, and because you can have up to 8 of them on the bus, you can control up to 128 items from a single Raspberry Pi.  I hope this helps!  here's a link for info: https://www.adafruit.com/product/732